# Difference between two time values, where time values are [h]:mm format and greater than 24 hours

Tags: microsoft-excel

All columns are formatted as `[h]:mm`

`=ABS(M5-I5)` (Where `M` is Hours middle col and `I` is 'Af Hours') formula keep giving me a `#VALUE!` error.

I would like the third column to give the difference between the two columns.

It seems like time calculations e.g. `*24` do not work for `[h]:mm` formatted cells when values are greater than `9999:59`

[image]

Comment: How did you enter those values?  If you entered them by typing them in directly, then they are really text strings (no matter how you've formatted them) and the `#VALUE!` result is expected.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I have copied some and entered some. I don’t really care about how they are formatted. I am just keen to know a method of finding a difference between two large time values.

Comment: Honestly I've never seen any such TIME format,,, it's neither Decimal nor Time format,,, in which country this is in use !!

Comment: I'm wondering that how you got this I mean which was the original value & then U applied [H]:mm format !!

Answer (score 2):

How you enter the value is of prime importance.

As is documented by MS in [Excel Specifications and Limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), ***"Largest amount of time that can be entered: 9999:59:59"***.

Any value that you have entered that is larger than that will be seen as **text**. Changing the numberformat of the cell does **NOT** convert that text string to a number.

In order to work with large time numbers, you can convert them into a time value that Excel will understand.

Therefore how you enter the values is most important.

The "safest" method would be to create a form where you enter the hours and minutes separately as integers, and then convert them to time with a mathematical formula.

They can then be formatted as time and you can add/subtract them as such.

If you are going to just type them into a cell in the format of ***h:mm***, you can use a formula directly on that entry.

Excel stores times as fractions of a day.  So the formula needs to:

- Check if the value is a number (in which case it needs no conversion
- If not a number, divide the hours portion by 24 (hours in a day), the minutes portion by 1440 (minutes in a day) and add the two.
- The result can then be treated as a time by excel.

This is not as robust as the user form method as it will allow you to enter "illegal" values, but for the data you present, the following formula will work:

```
=ABS(IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)/24+RIGHT(A1,2)/1440)-IF(ISNUMBER(B1),B1,LEFT(B1,LEN(B1)-3)/24+RIGHT(B1,2)/1440))
```

[image]

Comment: It's a rare Time format I've hardly since any such combination ,,, I've solved any Decimal to TIME,,, Decimal with un-common criteria ,,, you get +10 ☺

Comment: I've this one initially I've entered 2210 & 1452,,,  and  applied [h]:mm:ss then got  53040:00:00 & 34848:00:00 then applied your formula & got 00:00:00 (format is hh:mm:ss,, any idea !!

Comment: Actually your formula has mechanism to handle hour & minutes both so when I use 2210:10 with other then it's working with HH:MM:SS, but when I've used only the hour's part `=ABS(IF(ISNUMBER(A32),A32,LEFT(A32,LEN(A32)-3)/24)-IF(ISNUMBER(B32),B32,LEFT(B32,LEN(B32)-3)/24))` it doesn't works,,, even though I've applied [hh]:mm:ss. But I've got the solution use 2210-(1450/24) & HH:MM:SS it's working ,, anyway nice to Xchange ideas ☺

Comment: @RajeshS Now I see your mistake. You overlooked this line in my answer: *"type them into a cell in the format of h:mm"*. As I wrote, a user form for data entry would be more robust.

Comment: Okayy thanks ,, let me check ☺